# How to convert MySQL query to DB builder in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

How to convert a MYSQL query to a Laravel SQL query?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        year(invoiceDate) as [year],left(datename(month,invoicedate),3)as [month], 
        InvoiceAmount as Amount 
    FROM Invoice
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS pivot
```

Please anyone write this above code to Laravel DB Builder format using these methods.

eg: `$pivot=DB::table('Invoice')->where()...`

and also, `eg: $pivote=Invoice::where()->..`

How to write code for **pivot**?

Comment: I suggest you to use DB::RAW and DB::SELECT

Comment: That is not valid MySQL syntax. Looks more like SQL Server.

Comment: How to write this code using in DB::RAW and DB::SELECT.. method

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you implement your code with `DB:raw` and `DB::select`

```
$results =
    DB::select(
        DB::raw("
          SELECT *
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    year(invoiceDate) as [year],left(datename(month,invoicedate),3)as [month], 
                    InvoiceAmount as Amount 
                FROM Invoice
            ) as s
            PIVOT
            (
                SUM(Amount)
                FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
                may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
            )AS pivot
        ")
    );
```

**Note:** This is to show/demonstrate how to put an SQL statement inside `DB::raw` as per your request in the question, but this does not mean I have to check your SQL statement.